Error when combining SUM VLOOKUP across cells that contain blanks
I'm unable to get this formula to calculate based on current/real time value inputs without throwing an NA error. The formula will only calculate properly once there are no blank cells left in the row for the vlookup to have issues with.
You can see row 2 has no issue since all referenced cells are filled.
Problem: Row 5 will not calculate until all referenced cells with blank values are filled.
I tried multiple avenues of using sumifs, date functions, index matches, lookups, etc to no avail.
If the tracker is expanded out to a month at a time you can see how it's problematic for not calculating until the last day of the month.

Have the formula calculate based on the values that are present in real time, ignoring blank cells or automatically assuming they're zeros

=SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:H2,$L$2:$M$8,2,FALSE),"")) should work.

Or IFNA instead IFERROR, =SUM(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B1:H2,L$2:M$8,2,0),0))
